# Minimizing a function using a direct approach (no Lagrange multipliers).

Tags: multivariable-calculus, optimization

I want to minimize $g = x^2 + y^2$. My constraint is $h = 2x +y = l$. I know that using Lagrange multipliers is unnecessary here.

I solved the constraint to get $y = l - 2x$. I then substituted this result into $g$ to get the following:

\begin{align}
g &= x^2 + (l - 2x)^2\\
&= x^2 +l^2 - 4xl + 4x^2\\
&= 5x^2 - 4xl + l^2
\end{align}

Then I took the derivative with respect to $x$ and set it equal to zero:

\begin{align}
\frac{d g}{d x} &= 10x -4l\\
0 &= 10x -4l\\
10x &= 4l\\
x &= \frac{2}{5}l
\end{align}

Then I plugged this value for $x$ into $g$ to get the corresponding $y$ value, but that doesn't seem right. I ended up with $y = +\frac{2}{5}l$ and $-\frac{2}{5}l$.

Do I still take the partial with respect to $y$ and just end up with $0$ for $y$? Is my answer just going to be in terms of $l$? I've been assuming this whole time that the $l$ in the constraint equation is a constant-- does that seem right?

Comment: Without further context, I would assume that the $l$ is a constant. How do you get $y = \pm \frac{2}{5}l$? By the way, your notation $\partial g/\partial x$ is incorrect in this situation, since you are not holding $y$ constant for this derivative.

Comment: I fixed the notation. And $y = \pm \frac{2}{5}l$ came from plugging $x = \frac{2}{5}l$ into $g$. I don't know why I did that.

Comment: $g$ is not a constraint. you need to plug that value into $h$.

Comment: I plugged $x = \frac{2}{5}l$ into $h$ to obtain $y = \frac{1}{5}l$. I then plugged those two values into $g$ to get $\frac{1}{5}l^2$. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.